# htaccess how to redirect 404 to a variable url without causing infinite loop?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site when it lands on a 404 error on the first relative path of the url I want it to instantly redirect to a path relative to what the user typed.

So for instance input was: site.com/input
I want this first level url string to redirect to: site.com/m/input

I'm trying something like this, which works but causes an infinite loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/m%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

So basically, I want it to only fire once, and if the url at /m/{variable url} does not exist, then I want it to land on the actual 404 page or wordpress default's RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Is this possible?
Many thanks, 
Leon

Comment: This is working to redirect but the 404 page does not show up anymore, neither does the correct page. Both leads to the 404 page by the server not the template.

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !m

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/m%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another condition to not redirect if it's already an `/m/` URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/m%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Cheers mate, I used an alternative on the 404.php page instead, seems to work fine. 


    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


    if (false !== strpos($url,'/m/')) {
    } else {
    
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
 header("Location:    http://website.com/m/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
}